# JQuery - Image Loop Wait for Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following for loop that dynamically loads images onto a page.  For small numbers of images, say 10, it works great.  Beyond that, I start getting issues in loading the images, where the remote server is overwhelmed and not sending images (get red X's instead of images). The images are sent from the server from an imaging database, so unfortunately it is quickly overwhelmed.

```
for (var c = 0; c < b; c++) {
   url = transurl + "&action=getRelatedItem&docid="+ d[c].id +"&side=front";
   img = $("<img />").attr('src', url ).attr('width','600');
   allimages.append(img);
}
```

In this page, allimages is an empty div on the page.  I think I need to wait for an image to load before moving on and trying to load another one, and so on, but i'm not sure how to ask the loop to stop and wait for the image to load before moving on to the next one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that is a problem... the browser will manage the remote loading of resources

Comment: Do you mean that the red X's instead of images appear as a temporary thing while the images are loading, or that those images don't load at all? Because your code worked for me (in Chrome, IE11 and FF) with 200 different images: http://jsfiddle.net/3KgPr/ The images obviously don't all load instantaneously, so there may be the empty-box-with-red-X while they're still loading, but they all loaded within a reasonable amount of time. If you want to avoid the red X you can preload the images before appending them to your div.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  In doing some more testing on my side, it appears that the remote server may be causing the "Red X's" to appear and not the browser itself due to the amount of images attempting to load at once.  The images do appear to error out and not appear to be in the process of loading.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update : As per Kevin, adjusted the src assignment

I believe you're looking for a basic image preloader. I tried to adapt your current code, but I believe using the for loop for your current needs wouldn't be clean in terms of performance. So assuming you need to append each image sequentially when they are done loading :

```
var count = 0; // initial count is 0
allImages.on('insertImg', insertImgFn); // when event insert image is triggered, run insertImgFn

insertImgFn(); // runs the function once to start the loading process  << Edit

function insertImgFn(){
    url = transurl + "&action=getRelatedItem&docid="+ d[count].id +"&side=front";
    img = new Image(); // defines an image object
    $(img).load(function(){ // on image load completion
        var countMatch = count < b; // checks if your count is less than the amount of images
        if(countMatch){
            allImages.append(img); // appends your image
            count++; // increase the count
            allImages.trigger('insertImg'); // triggers the event 
        }// end of if countMatch
    });// end of .load
    img.src = url; // assigns the url to the image object
    $(img).width(600); // sets the width to the image
};// end of insertImgFn
```

Comment: Thanks for your code.  Unfortunately now realize it's the remote server causing the issue.  Is it possible to modify the code to force the images to load one-at-a-time instead of preloading?

Comment: The current code, starts loading one image, when it is done loading, it appends it to the DOM, and then starts loading the following image according to the count (Note : I ommited to call the function insertImgFn() at least once for the code to work, I will edit). Is it what you're actually requesting for? A code that loads an image, when done, loads another?

Comment: Swap your assignment of .src and the load event, otherwise this will fail on cached images. Load event binding first, then set the src.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your help.  This code works perfect.  Thanks!